# The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on a project where the reference is having 'AjaxControlToolKit' assembly added correctly. Also in the aspx file I have added the below tag:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Further in the aspx.cs file I have added the namespace to include Ajaxtoolkit controls:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

On the aspx.designer.cs file I get to see a control generated as below:

```
protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager ToolkitScriptManager1;
```

While building the project I get to see the below error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I removed and added the toolkit assembly correctly to the reference list and I also deleted and regenerated the designer file. Still no luck. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
```

in your aspx.cs